# How to get an oauth_token with oAuth in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, openx

I'm trying to authenticate using OAuth in [OpenX](http://docs.openx.com/api/#api_authentication.html) **(site does not render well in chrome. Use iexplore or safari.)**

This is my piece of code

```
# Login
$url = "https://sso.openx.com/api/index/token";
$post = http_build_query( array(  'Access Token URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/api/index/token',
                'Authorize URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/login/login',
                'callbackUrl' => 'oob',
                'Consumer Key' => $key,
                'Consumer Secret' => $secret,
                'OAuth Realm' => $realm,
                'Request Token URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/api/index/initiate',
                'Signature Method' => 'HMAC-SHA1 ',
                'Version' => '1.0a ') );

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($json_response);
curl_close($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($json_response);
```

And, according to the linked documentation, I should be expecting an *oauth_token* and *oauth_verifier*:

> 1.Set the callbackUrl to oob (out-of-band), which tells the OAuth server that you are not redirecting a user. The OAuth Server returns the request token.

but instead I'm getting:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - Invalid Request: Missing parameters

Am I doing something obviously wrong here that I am missing? Am I misunderstanding something in the linked documentation?

Any sort of help is welcome, either aimed at the problem itself or to the way it's been presented; answers, hints, ideas, corrections, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using openx too, here is my code. Hope it can help someone

```
$para = array (
        'Access Token URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/api/index/token',
        'Authorize URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/login/process',
        'callbackUrl' => 'oob',
        'Consumer Key' => $email,
        'Consumer Secret' => $consumer_secret,
        'OAuth Realm' => $sso_realm,
        'Request Token URL' => 'https://sso.openx.com/api/index/initiate',
        'Signature Method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'Version' => '1.0a'
);

$opt = array (
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://sso.openx.com/login/process",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookieFile,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookieFile,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $para,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{$authentication}",
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
);

$c = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($c, $opt);

$content = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
$error = curl_error($c);
```

You need the "consumer_secret" and "sso_realm" from the email openx people sent to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameters like this

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

where $data will have $data='username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'';

Answer (score -1):

Where does "$resource" come from?? Replace:

```
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

for a start.